# Post Method in IPhone programming for logining in to the application

Tags: ios, iphone

I am trying to Post the email and password in my iPhone application but I don't know why it says connection successful with out entering any data in to the text fields. Code below:

```
- (IBAction)enterButtonAction:(id)sender
    {
        NSString *post =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"user[email]=%@&user[password]=%@",[userNameTF text],[passWordTF text]];
        NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];

        NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[postData length]];
        NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] ;
        [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://secure.sample.in/login"]];
        [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
        [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
       // [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
        [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
        [request setHTTPBody:postData];
        NSURLConnection * connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:request delegate:self];


        if (connection) {
            NSLog(@"Connection Successfull");
        } else {
            NSLog(@"Connection UnSuccessfull");
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is your question exactly?

Comment: with out entering any text and pressing the button also it is printing connection Successfull

Comment: everything i given correctly but i dont know what wrong i am doing

Comment: You want to know how to run this code without textfields and how to run this code without press of a button?

Comment: i want to know if textfields are empty after pressing the button it must print Connection Unsuccessfull but why it is printing Successfull

Answer (score 2):

You have to actually run this connection. Right now you're just checking if `connection` pointer is not nil.
But it would be better just to use newest `NSURLSession` API.

So, something like this:

```
- (IBAction)enterButtonAction:(id)sender
{

    NSURLRequest *request = [self setupRequestWithData:...];

    NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];
    NSURLSessionDataTask *dataTask = [session dataTaskWithRequest:request
      completionHandler:^(NSData *data,
                          NSURLResponse *response,
                          NSError *error) {
        // handle response

    }];
    [dataTask resume];
}
```

Comment: That means i have to put the whole code in to the Blocks

Comment: Not really. You can skip the block and set yourself as `NSURLSession` delegate and impletement `NSURLSessionTaskDelegate`. See the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLSession_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSURLSession/delegate).

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
if (connection) {
    NSLog(@"Connection Successfull");
} else {
    NSLog(@"Connection UnSuccessfull");
}
```

is equivalent to

```
if (connection!=nil) {
    NSLog(@"Connection Successfull");
} else {
    NSLog(@"Connection UnSuccessfull");
}
```

Since `connection` isn't `nil`, the `if` condition is satisfied.

Comment: Yes, "Connection Successful" appears because `connection` is not `nil`.  If this is not the outcome you want then the condition you're testing is wrong.

Comment: That means there is no matter we enter email and password

Comment: The connection works. Whether you have authenticated or not is a different matter all together. You should get a successful connection that brings back something like "No user name supplied"

Comment: yaa i tried after i turned off my wifi even though it is printing Connection Successfull

Answer (score 0):

You could validate the username/password before executing the request.

`- (IBAction)enterButtonAction:(id)sender {
    if ([[userNameTF text] length] && [[passWordTF text] length]) {
        // Execute the request
    } else {
        // Missing username/password, show an UIAlertView?
    }
}`